# MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED fired when vast ad in JWPlayer

Tags: mp3, jwplayer, ads, vast

I'd like to serve audio ads on JWPlayer.

But when ad was called JWPlayer throws error code **"MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED"**.

Though Content-Type in the http header is audio/mpeg, in the vast is video/mp4.

Content type in the vast xml will affect the error in JWPlayer?

Following URL is test page.
http://webdemo.dac.co.jp/nt/radio/audio_test.html

javascript code for advertising is below.

```
advertising: {
    client: "vast",
    schedule: {
        preroll: {
            offset: "pre",
            tag: 'http://xp1.zedo.com/asw/fnsr.vast?n=2696&c=4/2&d=80&s=0&v=vast2&pu=__page-url__&ru=__referrer__&pw=__player-width__&ph=__player-height__&z=__random-number__',
            'skipoffset':1,
        },
        postroll: {
            offset: "post",
            tag: 'http://xp1.zedo.com/asw/fnsr.vast?n=2696&c=4/2&d=80&s=0&v=vast2&pu=__page-url__&ru=__referrer__&pw=__player-width__&ph=__player-height__&z=__random-number__',
        },
        adbreak1: {
            offset: 5,
            tag: 'http://xp1.zedo.com/asw/fnsr.vast?n=2696&c=4/2&d=80&s=0&v=vast2&pu=__page-url__&ru=__referrer__&pw=__player-width__&ph=__player-height__&z=__random-number__',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I am not too familiar with the JW player myself, the MediaFile node in the VAST XML should have the correct type attribute.

```
<MediaFile delivery="progressive" bitrate="300" width="1" height="1" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Using audio/mpeg tells the player not to expect a video and this prevents a media error.